# cannot assign decimal html special character to dom value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The value did not get interpreted and get printed straight.

```
document.getElementById("btn_more").value = "More &#9660;" ;
```

I also tried the following:

```
document.getElementById("btn_more").value = "More \&\#9660;" ;
document.getElementById("btn_more").value = "More \&#9660;" ;
```

Both did not work either.

& # 9660 ; supposed to be a down arrow.

Comment: Did you specify the encoding in your html start if its not html5?

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementById("btn_more").innerHTML = "More &#9660;" ;` ?

Comment: @Lal: That would work for `button`, but not for `input[type=button]`. The OP appears to have an `input` as she's trying to update what it shows by setting `value`.

Comment: @vinayakj: HTML numeric character entities use Unicode code points; the encoding of the text of the page doesn't matter.

Comment: @ Cindy: If the answer below *answered* your question, the way Stack Overflow works, you'd "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it; [more here](/help/somebody-answers). But only if it did; if not, don't hesitate to flag up what's not working. (I mention this because looking at your list of questions, it seems you might not be familiar with this part of SO.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `value` of an input isn't HTML text, so you can't use HTML character entities in it.

You can use a JavaScript unicode escape, though:

```
document.getElementById("btn_more").value = "More \u25BC";
```

(25BC is 9660 written in hexadecimal.)

---

Live example:

```js
document.getElementById("btn_more").value = "More \u25BC";
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn_more" value="More">
```